# How can I search all matched elements and put these "most precise" at the top of the listBox?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have about 10 sentences inside my new List(file.txt).  Example:

- Django Unchained is the first time in 16 years that Leonardo DiCaprio didn’t get the top billing.
- Django Unchained is a 2012 American revisionist Western film written and directed by Quentin Tarantino.
- etc.

When I enter text to search box: "Django Unchained Tarantino", I want to display the most precise result at the top of the listBox and the rest sentences under this particular. Any ideas?

Comment: Searching is a highly complex topic.  You aren't simply searching for a single phrase match.  You likely want to leverage an existing library (Elastic Search, Lucene, Solr) or even a cloud service (Azure Search, Coveo, etc)

Comment: How do you decide which result is the most precise on a conceptual level? Is it simply the result with the highest number of matching words? Does it give extra points for words appearing in the order the user provided them? Does it take into account inexact matches, e.g. if user accidentally typed "djagno unhained tarantello"? Depending on the precision metric, the algorithm may be more or less complex.

Comment: @Alice **"Is it simply the result with the highest number of matching words?"**
Exactly!
**Does it take into account inexact matches, e.g. if user accidentally typed "djagno unhained tarantello"?** No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word searching algorithm has several facets to it:

- what search criteria are supposed to represent (usually a set or a sequence of words, but it might be more elaborate with exclusions etc.)
- what search items are supposed to represent (likewise, usually a set or a sequence of words)
- the relevance metric, applying the search criteria to a specific search item

Since the asker said in comments that it's the result with the highest number of matching words, I'm going to present here such an approach. Of course, the more usable search we want, the more sophisticated algorithm we need.

First of all, we need to decide what makes a "word". For simplicity, I'm going to assume it's a continuous sequence of alphanumeric characters, and both search criteria and results are given as alphanumeric sequences separated with non-alphanumeric blocks. Thus, the following split method is used:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitSearchWords(string str)
{
    int charIndex = 0;
    int wordStart = 0;
    while (charIndex < str.Length)
    {
        wordStart = charIndex;
        if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(str[charIndex]))
        {
            while (charIndex < str.Length && char.IsLetterOrDigit(str[charIndex])) charIndex++;
            yield return str.Substring(wordStart, charIndex-wordStart);
        }
        else
        {
            while (charIndex < str.Length && !char.IsLetterOrDigit(str[charIndex])) charIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, we need a method to calculate the search relevance (I'm assuming that many occurrences of search word don't make the search item more relevant, thus I use Intersect method):

```
public static int CalculateSearchRelevance(string searchItem, IEnumerable<string> searchWords)
{
    var searchItemWords = SplitSearchWords(searchItem);
    return searchWords.Intersect(searchItemWords, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Count();
}
```

And finally, to put it all together:

```
var query = "Django Unchained Tarantino";
var items = new List<string>()
{
    "Django Unchained is the first time in 16 years that Leonardo DiCaprio didn’t get the top billing.",
    "pineapples",
    "Django Unchained is a 2012 American revisionist Western film written and directed by Quentin Tarantino.",
};

var searchWords = SplitSearchWords(query).Distinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToList();
var sortedItems = items.OrderByDescending(s => CalculateSearchRelevance(s, searchWords)).ToList();
```

Or, if you want to remove all items that are complete misses, you set the sortedItems to the following:

```
var sortedItems = items
    .Select(item => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(CalculateSearchRelevance(item, searchWords), item))
    .Where(relevanceItem => relevanceItem.Key > 0)
    .OrderByDescending(relevanceItem => relevanceItem.Key)
    .Select(relevanceItem => relevanceItem.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Depending on one's needs, there might be some adjustments made to determine how query is turned into search criteria or how relevance metric is calculated, but the general idea should remain roughly the same.

Comment: Thank you, it works! Do you know how to remove all elements which doesn't fit? Example: When I type word: "terminator" it should remove all elements from this list.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I made an edit to the post to include the case where we remove items with 0 relevance.

Comment: Could you help me once again? You asked: Does it take into account inexact matches, e.g. if user accidentally typed "djagno unhained tarantello"? Well... I'm affraid so :/ Thanks again for your help! Sorry for the inconvenience. Can't stand looking at this app another day...

Comment: Unfortunately, typos handling is significantly more complex and time-consuming case, so I don't really feel like making code for that. If I were to approach that problem, I'd probably apply approximate string matching techniques, as outlined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching Roughly speaking, I'd find the best match for each search query words, then sum up the word-wise similarity metric to get the overall score.

Comment: I understand.I am really grateful for your help. :)